# How can I download a file with Angularjs in client side and Java Restful in server side with POST?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, rest, csv

In JavaScript I have a array of data that need to download as csv file. 
The problem is currently in HTML, the attribute "download" is not available for Safari, but the requirement is that it must run for Safari (download attribute run good for Chrome and Firefox).
So I think about sending it to server and get the csv file from the server.
But currently I can not download directly a file on client side with a response from restful server. The response and data is in a promise and I don't know have to get the suggestion download from the browser.
Someone have any solution that can help me please ?

Comment: technologies? Backend java? spring?

Comment: We use resteasy, hibernate and spring framework.

Comment: I saw that we can use FileSaver,js to avoid going to server and compatible for other browser, but we cannot add more lib into our project. So is there any other solution ?